# wait() function behaviour

Tags: c, wait

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n,st;
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    while(n*fork()) {
        printf("%d %d\n",getpid(), getppid());
        n--;
        printf("%d\n", wait(&st));
        printf("------\n");
    }
}
```

I execute this code and I get the following results:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test 3
10218 9948
10219
------
10218 9948
10220
------
10218 9948
10221
------
```

**here are my thoughts:**
The parent is creating a child:

```
10218 9948
```

But after, I don't understand why the `printf("%d\n", wait(&st));` returns this id: **10219**.

The `wait()` should return the id of the child that terminates.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: The process id of the original process is 10218, the process ids of the children are 10219, 10220, 10221, etc. What's the issue?

Comment: The 9948 is your shell's PID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wait is not blocking because there's no reason to block. The child has already finished execution. This is because Linux will schedule the "child" process to run first.

Here is what's happening in graph form:

```
bash(9948)
|
|       main(10218)       child1(10219)       child2(10220)      child3(10221)
>-------------->
               |
             fork--------------->
                                |
                            while(0);
                            terminate;
                                |
             print 10218 9948---<
             wait (no block)
             print 10219
              |
             fork----------------------------------->
                                                    |
                                                while(0);
                                                terminate;
                                                    |
             print 10218 9948-----------------------<
             wait (no block)
             print 10220
              |
             fork----------------------------------------------------->
                                                                      |
                                                                  while(0);
                                                                  terminate;
                                                                      |
             print 10218 9948-----------------------------------------<
             wait (no block)
             print 10221
             terminate
               |
---------------<
```

Comment: @Elias no problem. Please feel free to mark as the correct answer if you feel it was helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

`fork` returns zero for the child process so only the original process enters the while loop; the children exit without printing anything.

Each time the parent prints its process id and its parent's process id and then prints the child process id as the return value of wait.

In your example the original process has pid = 10218 and it forks children with process ids 10219, 10220, 10221, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly ok.

If you are interested of the PID of the processes created by fork() you should print the returned value.

getpid will always return the PID of the main process, and getppid its parent's (the shell). Since they don't change it's no point to print them in the loop.